# How to fetch each and every field of data from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch the saved data from firebase, but the problem is that my code is fetching only the first field and not every field of data.

Here's what I am doing to fetch my data:

```
public void fetchDataFromFirebase() {
        retrieveRef = new Firebase("https://abc.firebaseio.com/data/");
        Query query = retrieveRef.orderByChild("postedOnDate");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    HRequests hRequests = postSnapshot.getValue(HRequests.class);
                    hDescription = hRequests.getHDescription();
                    hImage = hRequests.getHImage();
                    hLat = hRequests.getHLat();
                    hLng = hRequests.getHLng();
                    postedAtTime = hRequests.getPostedAtTime();
                    postedBy = hRequests.getPostedBy();
                    postedOnDate = hRequests.getPostedOnDate();

                    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(homelessImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "this got called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

P.S.: I'm sure that I have 5-6 fields of data in my firebase database.

Please let me know how to fetch them all.

Comment: Without seeing the corresponding data structure (the JSON as text, not as a screenshot), it'll be difficult to help. I also see that you're storing images in the Firebase **JSON** database and looping over them, something that has been recommended against time-and-time again in the past months.

Comment: What do you mean by first field? Do you mean the first child record?