# How to give accurate Firebase reference?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am generating some random 'Alphanumeric characters' and saving the data along with `GeoFire` location in it.

Here's how I am generating random alphanumeric characters:

```
String rac = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

The data is getting saved under this: `appname/anotherReference/rac/`

Now the problem is that how could I give the accurate reference of the randomly generated alphanumeric characters so that I can retrieve data from that?

Comment: As it stands, there is not enough information for me to help. I edited in hopes that others would be able to understand it better than me. If they don't, edit your question to include the [minimal *complete* code to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved just by giving simple reference like this: `https://appname.firebaseio.com/anotherReference/`.

I learned that there was no need to give reference of that `rac` too!

Anyways, [Chris Conway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5960425/chris-conway) helped me a lot in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

More information may be required, but I can definitely take a stab.

If you are creating a reference at appname/anotherReference and retrieving all children, you can say snapshot.getKey() on each child to retrieve the key (rac), which I believe is the particular value you're asking to access? If you made that visible in the app, then you can then copy and share that between users in a method of your choosing.

Comment: what type of more information should I provide you?

Comment: I've given an estimation of what I think could solve your problem. Can you advise me of if that estimation is incorrect and why, and I can aim to make my answer relevant. Is my answer appropriate to your question? And if not, why not?

Comment: Actually, the reference is somewhat like this `https://appname.firebaseio.com/appname/anotherReference/rac`, under this reference I am saving the data. So, what I want is the right reference which I should provide in order to retrieve the data from that reference.
I hope you got me!

Comment: Do you mean how you could see that same data later on the same device? Would it make sense to add child listeners to `https://appname.firebaseio.com/appname/anotherReference` to see that data once it has been added? That would give you a list of all data that reference, not just the one saved under `rac/`

Comment: No no! That's not what I want! I want to retrieve the data saved under the reference: `https://appname.firebaseio.com/appname/anotherReference/rac`. And as `rac` is randomly generated alphanumeric characters, I don't know how to get reference of it. Got it?

Comment: Sure, I see. Are you wanting to access that data immediately? Because if you've just saved the data, then you call `databaseRef.child("appname/anotherReference/rac").addListenerForSingleValueEvent` you should be able to receive back the data that you just stored in the `onDataChange` block.

Comment: You aren't getting my point! I just want to know how can I give reference to `rac` which is not a defined string but a randomly generated string. I don't know what it is while saving the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113244/discussion-between-chris-conway-and-hammad-nasir).

Comment: thanks, I solved this issue. Now, pls help with this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889841/how-to-fetch-each-and-every-field-of-data-from-firebase

Comment: Good to hear. Please include your solution as an answer or an edit to your question so others can learn from what you've posted.

Comment: Done! Now please answer this too, sir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889841/how-to-fetch-each-and-every-field-of-data-from-firebase